# Why Does x = a() + ab(); has different results in different machines?

Tags: c, function, operators

I have two functions in my c programs. Lets name them `a()` and `a()`. In some where in the code I use their result in an equation: take a look at this:

```
int number = 2;
int x;

int a(){
    number += 3;
    return number;
}

int b(){
    number *= 2;
    return number;
}

x = a() + b();

printf("%d", x);
```

Here I expect 15 to be printed. But I get 11. Can anybody explain this?

Comment: You are invoking undefnined behaviour.

Comment: OP,  how could such code be actually useful for anything?  Can you think if any reason to write or use such code with such side-effects?  I mean, it's REALLY bad coding, why would anyone do it?  Why did you do it?

Comment: I don't see why you get `11` since the precedence rules for the `+` operator cause evaluation from left to right. I get `15`. But, it's like asking why your bicycle behaves unexpectedly when you poke a spanner in the spokes.

Comment: @WeatherVane; What? Precedence do not play any role in order of evaluation.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  `+` does not guarantee left to right evaluation.

Comment: I thought I had contradicted: I was referring to this page, where it says evaluation is left to right for the `+` operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx

Comment: @WeatherVane; Then that page says wrong. It is not evaluation, but grouping of operands.

Comment: @WeatherVane That page says `Associativity`.

Comment: @haccks thank you, in that case, MS are stating their own policy, rather than any standard.

Comment: @WeatherVane:  From that page: "Only the sequential-evaluation (,), logical-AND (&&), logical-OR (||), conditional-expression (? :), and function-call operators constitute sequence points and therefore guarantee a particular order of evaluation for their operands."

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the page says *"associativity (the order in which the operands are evaluated)"*

Comment: @WeatherVane E.g `a + b + c` => `((a+b) + c)` (left to right). (a + (b+c)) if right to left.

Comment: As far as the C language definition is concerned, precedence and associativity only control grouping of operators and operands.  They do *not* control the order in which operands are evaluated.  For an expression like `a + b * c`, precedence and associativity mean that the *result* of `b * c` will be added to `a`, but the subexpressions `a`, `b`, and `c` may be evaluated *in any order*.  MSVC may guarantee that `b` and `c` are evaluated before `a`, but it's not required, and you shouldn't expect that behavior to be universal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is specifically written to be bad, (side-effects).  Nobody except a prof/TA would ever write such code.  It's not only not useful to the SO repository, such code is actively harmful by demonstrating bad practices without explaining that they are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement,

```
x = a() + b();
```

The order in which the functions a() and b() will be called is *unspecified*. But there's a sequence point before calling each function and after returning from each function.

That means there are two possible orders of calls:
1) a() first and then b().
2) b() first and then a().

In case (1), the result will be 15 and in case (2), the result will be 11. There's no undefined behaviour despite `number` being modified by both functions as a side-effect of function calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator does not guarantee that operands will be evaluated left to right.  In this case, `b()` is being evaluated before `a()`.